# How do I modify a Homebrew formula?

Tags: compilation, imagemagick, package, homebrew

I installed [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) via [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).

However, due to a bug I have with my current configuration, I need to adjust the compile flags for the formula and reinstall it.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

### Remove the existing version.

```
$ brew rm imagemagick
```

### Edit the formula.

```
$ brew edit imagemagick
```

This will bring it up in an editor; make sure your `$EDITOR` variable is set to your preference (for me: TextMate)

### Change it, save it, try *re*-installing it.

Because most installs use pouring/bottles to install a precompiled binary, you will likely see no change unless you "build from source":

```
$ brew reinstall --build-from-source [...]
```

You can use `--formula /path/to/imagemagick.rb` as an additional argument to the above command to ensure `brew` is installing the formula that was edited.

If you're comfortable with git, you may also want to make a branch first, and do your edits in a branch to guard against data loss.

Comment: How do I change it back to the original version? Do I just have to run `brew upgrade`?

Comment: You change it back to the original version with git. `git checkout mysql.rb` may suffice if you didn't commit. If you committed you need to revert the commit.

Comment: I have edited the formula but no 'install' method is being called from this file(tested by putting 'raise' statement just right in the beginning of the method) and imagemagick being installed successfully. I wonder what formula file does Homebrew use

Comment: To revert the edit you can use `git status` under `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` (or whichever tap you where using) and then do a a `git checkout <formulaname.rb>`

Comment: Also you can (without removing, just unlink) use "brew unlink <formula>", then "brew edit <formula>" and set the app version manually; after that you need to just fetch/download app with command "brew fetch <formula>", on result copy sha256 value, repeat brew edit <formula> and replace previous sha256 property. Then use "brew install <formula>". Don't forget to reset formula state with command: "cd $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/ ; git reset --hard HEAD"

Comment: After `brew edit` use `brew reinstall --build-from-source`. Even if you edit it, most installs use `pouring bottle` to install a precompiled binary. Your changes won't have an effect.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky This comment is super useful and should probably be added to the accepted answer by the author.

Comment: @valerio done. It was originally a case of "this might work for you", but now that it's gotten some upvotes, I feel comfortable being more forward. Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Great! Yeah, the original answer was not working for me, then I saw your comment, tried the command and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Removing the package seems to be an unnecessary step.  If you edit the formula and then do `reinstall --build-from-source` it will pick your changes up and reinstall the package with your changes.

Answer (score 10):

The *accepted answer* was the first step, but more was needed for my formula edit to work in **February 2023**.

If you edit formula *foo*, but your change is ignored by `brew reinstall --build-from-source foo` then, add `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1` to your shell config.  It makes *Homebrew* actually use your revised formula.

Details:  [Homebrew FAQ: Edit Formula](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#can-i-edit-formulae-myself)

Also, if you want your revised formula to persist, then run `brew pin foo`

Details: [Homebrew FAQ: Prevent Formula Update/Upgrade](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-stop-certain-formulae-from-being-updated)

Comment: **NOTE** 
Homebrew v4.0 (February 2023) may have changed/fixed some problems with persistent custom formulas.  
Check v4 Release Notes for details: https://brew.sh/2023/02/16/homebrew-4.0.0/