# How to handle Homebrew formula dependencies after having installed an older version

Tags: boost, dependencies, homebrew, versioning, downgrade

For various project-specific reasons, I have downgraded my `boost` (and `boost-python`) Homebrew installation to `boost159` from `boost` (aka Boost `1.62.0` as of the writing of this question). The `homebrew/versions/boost159` and `boost-python159` formulas are *keg-only* and therefore I had to link them manually:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew remove --force boost
brew remove --force boost-python
brew install boost159
brew link --force --overwrite boost159
brew install boost-python159
brew link --force --overwrite boost-python159
```

So far so good. But then, when I want to install some unrelated Homebrew formula that has a dependency on `boost`, Homebrew tries to `brew install boost` (Boost `1.62.0`) and fails to link it:

```
[34m==>[0m [1mPouring boost-1.62.0.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz[0m

[31mError:[0m The `brew link` step did not complete successfully

The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local

Could not symlink include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp

Target /usr/local/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp

is a symlink belonging to boost159. You can unlink it:

  brew unlink boost159


To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

  brew link --overwrite boost


To list all files that would be deleted:

  brew link --overwrite --dry-run boost


Possible conflicting files are:

/usr/local/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp -> /usr/local/Cellar/boost159/1.59.0/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp
[...]
```

Is there a way to make other formulas use `boost159` instead of `boost` ? Please note that `boost159` must be linked for other parts of the projects (not in my control) to work. That is, I can't leave it unlinked and set build variables instead.

PS. This is all taking place in a CI build actually, making the error much more disruptive.

**References**

- [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just have to [patch your local formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939651/how-to-modify-a-homebrew-formula). In my opinion the whole versions support in brew is an unholy hack and one of the reasons why I do not use brew for build time development dependencies.