# OpenMP/gcc on macOS : gcc --without-multilib not available

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, openmp, homebrew

Last year I had a school project that used the OpenMP API for parallel computing. I installed gcc-6 --without-multilib with the Homebrew (brew) tool. It worked like charm.

This year I had to make a new clean install of macOS High Sierra because of a software issue. Now I can't seem to install gcc without multilib with brew. When I type "**brew info gcc**", I can see the different install flags, and **--without-multilib** in not in this list. (I tried gcc@5, @6 and @7).

I tried installing gcc with the necessary flag (in case it just wasn't documented with "brew gcc info", with no luck.

If anyone has a solution, I'd be happy to test it.

Thanks, 
Clovel

PS : I obviously googled my issue, I didn't find anything useful. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939651/how-to-modify-a-homebrew-formula

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have no clue where to find the link to --without-multilib.

Like this : "--enable-checking=release",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little update. It seems that installing gcc 7.0 and beyond solves the problem, w/o the `--without-multilib` option. It looks like OpenMP support is native now.

It did solve the issue for me. *Do not forget* to update brew, and check that the compiler you ar eusing is the correct one.

'Till next time,

Clovel

Comment: If it doesn't solve the issue, please comment. The more feedback the better.