# Manually resolve error in homebrew formula

Tags: homebrew

While attempting to run the command `brew install mbedtls --HEAD` I encountered an error:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - include/mbedtls/config.h
```

I inspected the homebrew [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/mbedtls.rb) and see that `mbedtls`'s `include/mbedtls/config.h` is referenced on line 27.

I reviewed the [mbedtls git repo](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls) and sure enough, the file `include/mbedtls/config.h` no longer exists.  I searched through the commit history and can see that [`config.h` was renamed to to `mbedtls_config.h`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/commit/bb0cfeb2d4b34eb3ec932ca8b8e215f49b703153).

How do I go about manually resolving the filename error in the homebrew formula?

Comment: I think current mbedtls --HEAD, based on 3.0.0, is broken. To return to last stable release, 2.27.0, I downloaded https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/28e9ee3afc1a4cc65ea4cc89d6e21bc0158525be/Formula/mbedtls.rb and then I installed it with `brew install ~/Downloads/mbedtls.rb`.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/81285 was merged a few hours ago. I was successfully able to upgrade mbedtls from 2.27.0 to 3.0.0 just now. So that problem has now resolved itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my original question was found using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939651/how-do-i-modify-a-homebrew-formula).

The local source for the formula can be edited using
`brew edit formula_name`

Even with the change homebrew was still unable to complete the install, but provided more useful error messages that allowed me to locate the relevant resources:

```
READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
mbedtls 3.0.0 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/80727
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels.
```

Comment: This PR that you're referencing was closed without being merged. Possible new PR to follow is at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/81285