# Change Python version in Homebrew Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, homebrew, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to install jupyterlab via homebrew using:

```
brew install jupyterlab
```

Per the documentation here (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jupyterlab), this specifically installs a version of jupyterlab that relies on Python 3.11. However, I have a dependency on a package that is not yet updated to 3.11. Is there a way to tell brew's installed version of jupyterlab to use Python 3.10 instead?

I have tried a few things:
0. Installing python 3.10 in brew with:

```
brew install python@3.10
```

1. Unlinking and/or uninstalling Python3.11 to try to force jupyterlab to use 3.10 with:

```
brew unlink python@3.11
```

```
brew uninstall python@3.11
```

and then specifically linking 3.10:

```
brew link python@3.10
```

But these don't seem to affect what jupyterlab sees or uses.

I see on the brew page that it says:

> Additional kernels can be installed into the shared jupyter directory
> $(brew --prefix)/etc/jupyter

But I don't understand what this means or how this installation happens.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (which I recently learned about) is to *edit* your local copy of the `jupyterlab` formula, to make it depend on Python 3.10.  I successfully did this for the `yt-dlp` formula.

Check out this question for details: [how-do-i-modify-a-homebrew-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939651/how-do-i-modify-a-homebrew-formula/75520170#75520170)